# 422 (Unprocessable Content)

Tags: python, reactjs, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to make a post method in react to my apigateway RestApi with lambda, but the response that I'm getting is this.

POST https://api_url/create-user 422 (Unprocessable Content)
undefined

In Postman I get the right response, but in my code don't.

React code ->

```
  const [responseMessage, setResponseMessage] = useState('');

  async function response() {
    try {
      const requestBody = {
        body_here
      };

      fetch('api_url_here/create-user', {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          setResponseMessage(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          setResponseMessage('Error: ' + error.message);
        })

        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          setResponseMessage(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          setResponseMessage('Error: ' + error.message);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

What I'm returning in the lambda ->

```
return {
            "statusCode": self.status_code,
            "headers": {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",  # Required for CORS support to work
            },
            "body": json.dumps(self.body)
        }
```

Comment: Related Q&A [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QU0IUokp8dRViDWO9s1Nbjkw/unexpected-end-of-json-input-code-422).

Comment: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` is a backend header. setting it on the frontend does nothing